# Dropdownlist get table Id of selected item, not dropdownlist id

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a dropdownlist populated by database and I need to get the Customer Table "Id" for the selected Name, but instead I get the selectedIndex of the dropdownlist, which doesn't correspond to the table;

This populates dropdownlist with 4 names in alphabetical order by last name, So Miko Alcot is first, and the dropdown gives Miko a selectedIndex of "1", but I need the Customer Table Id, of "4". How do I get that? I'm using dropdownlist.SelectedIndex.ToStrgin() and it gives me the dropdown's selected index, not the table Id corresponding to the name.

```
Customer Table          GenericAttribute Table             

Id     Username             EntityId     Key     Value
1        foo                    1       fname    John
2        bar                    1       lname     Doe
3        flip                   2       fname    Greg
4        flop                   2       lname    Zowiski
                                3       fname    Paula
                                3       lname    Lindhurst
                                4       fname    Miko
                                4       lname    Alcot

 Dim Adapter9 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [firstname] + ' ' + [lastname] As Name, Id, UserName From (Select a.Id, a.UserName, b.[key], b.[Value] From Customer a INNER JOIN GenericAttribute b ON a.Id = b.EntityId Where UserName IS NOT NULL) org PIVOT (MAX([Value]) For [Key] In ([firstname], [lastname])) pvt Order by [lastname] ASC", "Data Source=myDataSource")
    Dim Dataset9 As New DataSet
    Adapter9.Fill(Dataset9, "Customer")
    ddlUsers.DataSource = Dataset9
    ddlUsers.DataTextField = "Name"
    ddlUsers.DataValueField = "Id"
    ddlUsers.DataBind()
    ddlUsers.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select User--", "0"))
```

Comment: in selected index changed event add following code  ddlUsers.selectedValue  and check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Comments

in `selected index changed even`t add following code `ddlUsers.selectedValue` and check again

Answer (score 1):

You can use SelectedIndexChanged event to check ddlUsers.SelectedValue property.